# Highest Performance Method of Updating ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that will be updated once per second to do some basic checks and maintain a list of players that are currently meeting a set of conditions.

I'm wondering what the highest performing way to do this is I have 2 proposed solutions.

```
public void update() {
    for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (!playersOnLadder.contains(player)) {
            if (checkPlayerOnLadder(player)) {
                playersOnLadder.add(player);
            }
        } else {
            if (checkPlayerOnLadder(player)) {
                playersOnLadder.remove(player);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void update() {
            playersOnLadder.clear();

    for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (checkPlayerOnLadder(player)) {
            playersOnLadder.add(player);
        }
    }
}
```

There would generally be about 75 players in this array list at any given time. The "Check player on ladder method looks like this:

```
private boolean checkPlayerOnLadder(Player player) {
    int ladderAbsolute = this.getX()+this.getZ();
    int playerAbsolute = (int) player.getLocation().getX()+ (int) player.getLocation().getZ();

    //If the player is within 4 blocks (2 in each direction) of the ladder then return true.
    if (ladderAbsolute == playerAbsolute || (ladderAbsolute-2 > playerAbsolute && ladderAbsolute+2 < playerAbsolute)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDITED converted to a HashSet

Comment: Your code looks odd - if the list *already* contains a player, you potentially add it again? I would concentrate on making the code clear and correct first, then *measure* the performance to work out whether or not it's good enough. But correctness is more important.

Comment: As a side note; is the order of the list important, because I note you use playersOnLadder.contains(player), contains() is horrible on ArrayLists. HashSets are better for contains

Comment: For the second alternative? It's not possible to add the player multiple times because we clear this list both times to avoid needing to invoke checkPlayerOnLadder and the ArrayList methods excessively.

Comment: Richard, thanks for the recommendation, order is not important. Just converted it to a HashSet now.

Comment: If playersOnLadder isn't updated very often, consider sorting it and then use binary search. Eg. if a lot of players are entering the ladder and staying there for long time. You may use TreeList for this - it will speed up process of checking if player is still on ladder.

Comment: @MatthewSalsamendi: No, I still think you've got a bug. Look at your code again - you *only* call `playersOnLadder.add(player)` if `playersOnLadder.contains(player)` has returned `true`. How can that be what you want?

Comment: If you're concerned about speed, then write a test to compare.

Comment: Once per second isn't that much. If you have once per milli-seconds, I still wouldn't worry about it unless you have measured it.  The simplest way to speed up your code is to make sure it is warmed up and compiled to native code by the JIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If restricted to these two options, then I would go with option number 2 as the higher performing solution.

In option 1, the `remove` operation in an `ArrayList` is O(n), because it must find the player, O(n) and remove the player if found, shifting everyone further down backwards at O(n).  Looping over the entire players list this way is O(n^2).

Option 2 simply clears the list to start with, at O(n).  The `add` operation is O(1) (unless resizing is necessary), so adding them all is also O(n).  Option 2 is overall O(n).

Replacing your `ArrayList` with a `HashSet` (and implementing `hashCode` and `equals` on `Player`) could be an option.  Hash operations are O(1), so looping over all players and performing these operations is also O(n).  If you need to find a particular `Player` quickly later, then go with a `HashSet`, because `contains` is O(1) in a `HashSet` but O(n) in an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use a dictionary type data structure for this kind of bookkeeping.
A HashSet (make sure to implement hashCode correctly!) is most probably what you want. Semantically and performance wise.

I did not understand your ladder and accompanying algorithm, though.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to use a `HashSet`, but [`Player`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html) [doesn't override `hashCode`](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/entity/Player.java), so [`HashMap<int, Player>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) will work, using Player's [entityId](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/Entity.html#getEntityId%28%29).

Something like this:

```
HashMap<int, Player> playersOnLadder; /* make sure to initialize this */

public void update() {
    for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (checkPlayerOnLadder(player)) {
            playersOnLadder.put(player.getEntityId(), player);
        } else {
            playersOnLadder.remove(player.getEntityId());
        }
    }
}
```

Because it's a `HashMap`, `put`ing multiple times is fine, and `HashMap.remove` is safe to call if the given obejct isn't in the map (it will return `null`, but there's no need to check for it in this case).

---

Even better than this would be changing your code to use [events](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference). It looks like [PlayerJoinEvent](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerJoinEvent.html) and [PlayerQuitEvent](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerQuitEvent.html) may be useful to you, and whatever it is your `checkPlayerOnLadder` function does might be able to be done in response to an event.

Comment: Is it strictly nessissary to override the .hashcode () method? Wouldnt the default,  memory location based one behave much like a player ID

Comment: Events was the next thing I wanted to consider, but it would be cumbersome because it would have to be implemented on top of PlayerMoveEvent which fires dozens of times per second per player.

Comment: @RichardTingle It's hard to say without knowing the application. I wouldn't depend on it.

Comment: @Richard Tingle: Yes, as long as you never has two different Player objects which should be equals, it's fine. You could get problems when loading or saving players. ID based equals and hashCode are trivial and more flexible.

Comment: The problem is that the Player object is being pulled from an external API and I'd prefer not to override their methods without actually seeing it.

Comment: @MatthewSalsamendi I actually looked it up. They don't override `hashCode()`, so it would be better to use a `HashMap<int, Player>` using `Player.getEntityId()` as the key (see the new edit).

Answer (score 0):

"75 players" + "once per second" => move on!

You may be able to gain a few nanoseconds every second, which could make your code a few 0.0000001% faster...

Now the faster option would probably be this (allocation is generally cheaper than clearing):

```
public void update() {
    // pre sizing the list saves unnecessary resizing operations.
    playersOnLadder = new ArrayList<>(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers());
    for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (checkPlayerOnLadder(player)) {
            playersOnLadder.add(player);
        }
    } 
}
```